# How to fix ".cuda()" showing error in google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, machine-translation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01zpx.png)

Here, "model = model.cuda()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose gpu.

from Runtime -> change runtime type and select GPU as accelerator

Answer (score 0):

When you want your notebook to be able to use GPU, you need to edit the settings.

go to Edit >> Notebook settings >> Hardware accelerator >> GPU >> Save >> restart the runtime

[image]

[image]